# Setup multiple SSL certificates on amazon VPC

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to setup multiple SSL certificates on an amazon VPC instance (**I'm using amazon's standard linux AMI**)

Here's what I did:

1. I setup a VPC instance
2. Added a secondary private IP address
3. Added 2 elastic IP addresses & "linked" them to the private ones
4. Went to my domain registrar & pointed two test domains to the elastic IP addresses
5. Waited until new IP addresses were propagated
6. I uploaded the SSL certificates to the VPC instance

Then I tried editing [ssl.conf, see line 74 to 93](http://pastebin.com/tGqbbTm0) & [httpd.conf, see line 1046 to 1086](http://pastebin.com/tyaj7qPL):

### ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost domain1.com:443>
    ServerName www.domain1.com:443
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    SSLENGINE on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/domain1_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/domain1_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/domain1_com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ...Default SSL certificate (domain1.com) here...
</VirtualHost>
```

### httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried `<VirtualHost *:443>` and `<VirtualHost IP.ADDRESS:443>`, didn't work either.

The result is basically this:

1. domain1.com (which is the default SSL certificate) works just fine (resolve fine, green bar)
2. domain2.com: doesn't even resolve to anything, even though when I do `ping www.domain2.com`, **I get the correct elastic IP**

**My question is**: Any idea how to make domain2.com resolve & use the correct SSL certificate?

---

### EDIT / Additional Info:

I also tried this:

1. Temporarily stopped firewall as suggested, ie. `sudo service iptables stop`
2. From outside of EC2, `curl --connect-timeout 10 https://domain2.com` gave me this  `curl: (28) connect() timed out!`

`wget https://www.domain2.com/` gave me this: `--2013-10-03 15:57:22-- domain2.com Resolving www.domain2.com... 54.229.111.22 Connecting to www.domain2.com|54.229.111.22|:443... failed: Connection timed out. Retrying.`

---

### EDIT (2):

I noticed 2 things:

1. If I use 2 network interfaces (each NIC with one private IP) `sudo ifconfig`  doesn't show the 2nd NIC (ie. `eth1`), and wether I use one or two NICs, `sudo ifconfig` always return the 1st private IP (10.0.0.10), never the 2nd one (10.0.0.183)

Unsurprisingly, the unreachable website `domain2.com` corresponds to the 2nd IP (which is missing): 10.0.0.183

1. This command `curl --interface 10.0.0.10 ifconfig.me` correctly retuns the elastic IP address associated to `domain1.com` while

This command `curl --interface 10.0.0.183 ifconfig.me` retuns:

```
curl: (45) bind failed with errno 99: Cannot assign requested address
```

1. I [followed this guid](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=94619&tstart=75), I can see `eth1`, but `domain2.com` is **still unreachable**

And `curl --interface 10.0.0.183 ifconfig.me` now returns this:

`curl: (7) Failed connect to ifconfig.me:80; Connection timed out`

Comment: Are you saying "domain2.com" (without www) doesn't ping with the correct IP (or any IP? "unknown host?") but "www.domain2.com" does?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: No, domain2.com does ping to the correct IP address, but neither `domain2.com` nor `www.domain2.com` resolve correctly :(

Comment: Okay, I would say you're using the wrong term to describe your problem, then... if you ping by name and get the correct address, that is the definition of "resolving correctly."  Are you able to connect to the web server but you get the wrong certificate?  Or what exactly happens when you try to hit domain2.com with a web browser, or -- better -- wget or curl?

Comment: `<VirtualHost private.internal.ip.address:443>` should be the correct setting, as shown in the config file you posted.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: I believe I used the correct terms, please don't be confused: I don't have any issue with **domain1**.com (it resolve correctly and certificate is OK), the issue is with **domain2**.com: it just doesn't resolve, I can't even connect to check the certificate :(

Comment: Yes, I followed `datasage` advice, I restarted apache, but it **domain2**.com doesn't resolve :(

Comment: From outside of EC2, `curl --connect-timeout 10 https://domain2.com` returns what response, please?

Comment: I got this using a server outside EC2: `curl: (28) connect() timed out!`

Comment: `wget https://www.domain2.com/` gave me this:
--2013-10-03 15:57:22--  https://www.domain2.com/
Resolving www.domain2.com... 54.229.111.22
Connecting to www.domain2.com|54.229.111.22|:443...
failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.`

Comment: Well, you should be able to eliminate apache from the list of things that might be the problem, at least for now, and look further outward -- because if apache weren't listening, you should have seen "connection refused."  Does `sudo ifconfig` show that your instance is aware of the secondary private IP address?

Comment: Thanks! [**Yes, it does**](http://pastebin.com/5xzcj3La), both `10.0.0.10` and `10.0.0.83` are listed

Comment: How about verifying the configuration or temporarily shutting down `iptables`?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following :( Which configuration should I check? VPC/Amazon? or OS/centos? I did `sudo service iptables restart` but the issue is persistent :(

Comment: Sorry, I meant "verifying the configuration of iptables" ... `sudo service iptables stop` to drop the firewall to verify whether traffic starts passing (meaning it's not configured correctly).

Comment: Got it. I stopped the firewall, but I'm still having the same issue (curl also gave the same error as before) :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=94619) fixed it for me

One small (but important) note:

Instead of typing this command (step #5):

```
echo "1 admin" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

You should do this instead:

```
sudo vi /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

then add `1 admin` at the end of the file

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use ip based virtual hosting for SSL. The IP address you are going to listen will be the private, not public IP.

Your sites on port 80 can use name based virtual hosting. But you need to make sure you are using this directive: `NameVirtualHost *:80`

Comment: I followed your advice (See [httpd.conf, line 1046 to 1086](http://pastebin.com/tyaj7qPL) and [ssl.conf, line 74 to 93](http://pastebin.com/tGqbbTm0)), but I'm experiencing the same behavior: domain1.com work just fine, but domain2.com doesn't even resolve, even though `ping www.domain2.com` resolve just fine to the correct IP address!

Comment: @datasage thank you so much for the tip. Very very helpful. I almost 1 whole day trying to debug 2 ip on vpc ec2 and wasn't able to make it work. Your suggestion really really help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to follow a troubleshooting methodology for this.

**Start by simplifying your configuration** and verifying the basic components, then gradually build it up to the complete solution. For example:

- Map the elastic IP for domain2 to a new EC2 server.
- On the new server, start by making domain2.com available over HTTP
- Once it is working over HTTP, set it up to work over HTTPS
- Once it is working over HTTPS map the elastic IP back to the original server and make it work on the original server using HTTP
- Once it is working over HTTP take the final step of getting it to work over HTTPS on the original server.

The aim here is to validate each step and isolate exactly where it is going wrong. This will then enable you to best direct your energies for solving the root cause.

Comment: Steps #1, #2 & #3 --> OK. But when I map the elastic IP back to the first instance so that I can have two IPs/websites working from one instance, `www.domain2.com` doesn't work anymore! (connect timeout)

Comment: Ok, so the problem isn't related to the SSL portion of the config. Is your EC2 instance running within a VPC? (I'm wondering if it might be related to the VPC Network ACLs or something similar).

Comment: Yes, it's within a VPC indeed

Comment: OK, I edited my question to add more info /things that I noticed (see `EDIT (2)` section at the end)...thanks!